# Why would an Nginx HTTP to HTTPS redirect not work for the www subdomain

Tags: http, https, redirection, nginx

I configured NGINX to redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

(Not literally domain.com, but my actual domain name)

The redirects are working correctly for domain.com, but when I try accessing www.domain.com, I still get the HTTP version.

Any idea why that could be?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, had the Let's Encrypt certbot adding another `listen 80` directive to my HTTPS server block.

Fixed by leting Let's Encrypt manage HTTP -> HTTPS rules (pass "--redirect" to cerbot command).